# Decrypting message with purposefully weak private key hangs indefinitely

Tags: python, rsa, pycryptodome

I'm having issues when generating a public key from a private key, which has been weakened deliberately, and attempting to encrypt/decrypt a message when using PyCryptoDome. The decrypt just seems to hang indefinitely.

**Note: obviously this isn't my real private key**. The following key is weakened, on purpose:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The following snippet is used to read the private key, derive a public key, encrypt a message and then decrypt it again:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import Crypto.Util
from base64 import *

def encryptMsg(rsakey, message):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsakey)
    ct = cipher.encrypt(message)
    return ct

def decryptMsg(rsakey, message):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsakey)
    pt = cipher.decrypt(message)
    return pt

key = RSA.importKey(open('private.key').read())
testpk = key.publickey()
message = b64encode(encryptMsg(testpk, b"test message"))
print(message)
print(decryptMsg(key, b64decode(message)))
```

This seems to hang when calling `decryptMsg()`.

Comment: I get an exception on trying to import the key: *ValueError: RSA key format is not supported*, because the `u` component (exponent2) is 1, which PyCryptodome seems to think is an invalid value but `openssl rsa -check` tells me is valid.  That's not the problem *you* see, but it is a problem with PyCryptodome and the key you gave here in your question.

Comment: However, how did you get a private key with such a tiny, tiny prime number as *5*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your answers. Ah yes I purposefully created the public/private keypair with a tiny prime number as I'm experimenting with weak keypairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving PyCryptodome a private key with hugely disproportionate prime numbers, and the security of this key is essentially broken because of this. You note this in your question, but it is important here because PyCryptodome seems to make assumptions about the magnitude of the prime numbers.

To be secure, RSA public key encryption normally requires the use of two prime numbers [that are close in magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation):

> For security purposes, the integers *p* and *q* should be chosen at random, and should be similar in magnitude but differ in length by a few digits to make factoring harder.

You appear to have weakened the key by making the second prime a single-digit value:

```
$ openssl rsa -in private.key -text -noout | sed '/prime1:/,/prime2:/!d;/prime2:/q'
prime1:
    29:2b:9a:28:ee:ef:80:1f:0c:86:56:1b:30:c5:06:
    a0:88:08:80:b3:c9:cd:56:18:6a:da:a4:26:99:77:
    19:f4:22:a0:a7:4c:1e:28:d1:20:01:88:5d:23:59:
    5e:7f:0a:b3:cf:38:3a:6a:5b:2a:a6:c7:fd:c4:a1:
    46:7e:3d:10:07:c8:18:79:d1:d1:a1:79:8d:95:fa:
    34:14:b2:36:96:e3:90:ac:d6:5d:01:10:6c:7a:1d:
    8e:94:e5:e5:96:85:c4:a6:54:5b:4f:a4:2d:7a:97:
    dc:7c:50:2f:03:76:72:2b:ee:5c:3a:22:4d:11:b5:
    f8:a3:cd:92:26:85:56:58:40:3d:86:ec:61:28:33:
    81:b2:3f:e5:5e:6a:65:47:a6:78:bd:a0:db:5e:33:
    1c:2f:64:aa:2e:7c:fa:3f:c9:7f:09:44:e5:68:ac:
    83:97:7b:6b:8e:47:3a:64:62:8e:ab:0b:dc:3b:ba:
    81:9d:5f:96:bd:7d:37:0d:f9:48:ce:e4:96:39:b2:
    65:d2:04:19:7c:1c:a7:0e:95:6d:42:ce:74:76:2c:
    7d:13:6a:0e:ce:4d:8a:34:8a:fd:22:f5:ee:5a:4e:
    0c:15:7c:7b:14:bc:c6:a0:cf:a6:74:92:45:a9:d4:
    e5:b4:f3:e3:d0:78:59:38:c4:3f:a0:ac:77:4f:de:
    07
prime2: 5 (0x5)
```

The `prime1` (the *p* value) is a 'proper' large prime using 617 digits, while the second *q* prime is a single digit value, so *p* is about 10 ^ 616 times larger. Using this key then triggers a worst-case scenario in the way PyCryptodome handles RSA decryption.

During decryption the implementation is [trying to make a negative number positive by repeatedly adding the second prime number](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py#L161-L163):

```
m1 = pow(cp, self._d % (self._p - 1), self._p)
m2 = pow(cp, self._d % (self._q - 1), self._q)
h = m2 - m1
while h < 0:
    h += self._q
```

In the above code, the `_p` and `_q` attributes are the two prime numbers, and `_d` is the private key exponent

Because your given private key is using two prime number of such *hugely disproportionate* prime numbers (1 digit vs 616 digits), the value for `m2` is *3*, while `m1` is a 616 digits short. As a consequence, trying to add *q* (5) to a negative integer 616 digits long will take a *very long time*. On my aging Macbook Pro laptop, the GMP wrapper used by PyCryptodome can add a small integer to that large integer 1 million times in about 6 seconds:

```
timeit("a + b", "from Crypto.Math._IntegerGMP import IntegerGMP as H; a = H(-529888206800322351142280698970509553244088870105926093960960600839997948364537263924658051221855219286822834908160253952313431263065035892252247530580840707934254014192645042780064071400938165792458671917549294961637063901428635522475550885330295366860440266592481901428697979715456902249133738633092402578072834537512045684962133176512203248846326955899359525113708331947304401283815041620003402445741404924361709787545141518988924507726836779489762118740731196007268258996956015186886831392340919980371282865371496239488099989353283964607756716132847721450221986689589881754517900556993453537792486255692015472770); b = H(5)")
5.970772444999966
```

To complete that `while` loop would have to iterate another 10 ^ 609 times and the total amount of time my laptop would take, would require 603 digits just to express the number of millions of years required. I don't expect the universe to even last that long, let alone my laptop.

It should just use a modulus operation; you can replace the `while h < 0: h += self._q` loop with a modulus operation here:

```
if h < 0:
    h %= self._q
```

This is `Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py`, in `def _decrypt(self, cyphertext):`, line 162 in version 3.9.3. With that change decryption is again almost instant.

I've filed this [as a bug with the PyCryptodome project](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues/347) (now closed as fixed) and the project released [version 3.9.4](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/changelog.html#november-2019) with the loop replaced by a modulus operation.

If you don't want to alter your installed copy of PyCryptodome and are blocked on this, you could switch to using the [`cryptography` project](https://cryptography.io/), as it doesn't have this problem. PyCryptodome implements the RSA algorithms itself, while `cryptography` delegates decryption to the `openssl` library.

Comment: Excellent analysis Martijn!